# Slide only half Fragment while using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an application where I'm using a ViewPager to slide between two Fragments. I can slide between two Fragments perfectly; but now I need to slide only half of the fragment. How to do that? Here is what I've tried:

This my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
      MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
      Context c;
      int[] pics = {R.drawable.ic_launcher};

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        c = MainActivity.this;
        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), c, pics);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
      }
    }
```

PageAdapter.java

```
        class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
          Context c;
          int[] pics;
          Fragment fragment;

          public MyPageAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm,  Context c, int[] pics) {
            super(fm);
            this.c =c;
            this.pics = pics;
          }

          @Override 
          public Fragment getItem(int position) {
              switch(position){
              case 0:return new MyFragment();
              case 1: return new NewFragment();
              default: return new MyFragment();
              }
          }

          @Override
          public int getCount() {
            return 2;
          }
        }
```

MyFragment.java

```
        public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
             public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
             public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message,int a)
             {
                 MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
                 return f;
             }

             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {

               View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
               TextView messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
               messageTextView.setText("hi");
               v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
               return v;
             }
    }
```

NewFragment.java

```
        public class NewFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message,int a)
         {
           MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
           return f;
         }

         @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment, container, false);
           Button b1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.b1);
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
           return v;
         }
    }
```

Comment: did you found any way to do that ? if yes , please share it

Answer (score 0):

Override the `getPageWidth` method of `PagerAdapter` and make it `return 0.5f;`

Comment: But it will display half of both the pages and we cant even slide

Comment: Then I haven't understood you question correctly. What do you mean by "need to slide only half of the fragment"?

Comment: I mean the whole first Fragment must be displayed but when I slide then half of first slides out and half of 2nd Fragment slides in

Comment: @user3201291 check the position , if it was the fragment that u want then `return 0.5` else , just `return 1.0`